# Remotely Call Page to Execute in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I have a system in which I allow users (admins) to request batch emails be sent. I would like it to make it so that when the request is made I programatically ping a page (passing query string values)

I want to do it this way instead of just executing the method on the page its called because I'm afraid of the user leaving the page before the method is done executing - is my approach correct? Could someone point me in the right direction with sample code as I'm not even sure what code to use to make this happen.

Comment: It is not clear what problem you are trying to solve. Can you please explain the issue in detail?

Comment: Sorry - I'm trying to remotely call a page via C# - for example, the admin posts a new message, by default I have a scheduled task that runs in the background and checks every 15 minutes for new messages to bulk email out to new users - well I want to give the admin the ability to send email immediately (bypassing this 15 minute wait) - however, in doing so if I called the method upon them clicking a button and they were to leave that page - would it not only cause a partial email send instead of a full email send?

Comment: My thoughts are in by calling a page programatically that the page will not execute under that users web browser session so that if they close out of the page or navigate to a new page it will not stop that method from executing - i hope this makes sense, its kinda hard to explain

Comment: What page are you talking about? If a web page, the request is running, them leaving the page at the point will not abort the thread. The thread will only abort when the session times out.

Comment: Hi Oded, I see - I was not aware of this, sorry for my ignorance, I suppose this negates my entire question then - sorry for the waste of time! thanks for the education!! its very much appreciated - is it possible you could put this as an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments in your question, the whole premise is incorrect.

When a user leaves a page after clicking a button, this will not abort the request on the server - the server will continue to process the request as normal (the server can't tell that the user has left the page - this is a consequence of HTTP being a stateless protocol).